# Doubts in query conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables

**1.Employee**

```
EMP_NAME,

EMP_CODE
```

**2.Vacations**

```
EMP_NAME,

EMP_CODE,

VACATION_START_DATE-->date type

VACATION_END_DATE-->date type,
```

My question is how to query to get the `EMP_NAME` from table1(Employee), where the today is not in between `VACATION_START_DATE` and `VACATION_END_DATE` from table2(Vacations)..

Comment: How are emp names and codes related acreoss the tables e.g. if emp_code is the same in both is emp_name the same?

Comment: @Mark I posted the answer assuming that it was a typo... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this please: assuming that you do not have `emp_name` vacations table..as well as `emp_code` as the relationship between the two table. So you can use `join`s.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe11a/1)

```
select e.emp_code, e.emp_name, 
v.start_date, v.end_Date
from emp e
inner join
vacation v
on e.emp_code = v.emp_code
where not (Now() between v.start_date 
and v.end_date)
;

| EMP_CODE | EMP_NAME |                      START_DATE |                        END_DATE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |     john | December, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 | December, 20 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|        2 |     kate | December, 20 2012 00:00:00+0000 | December, 30 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|        3 |      tim | December, 24 2012 00:00:00+0000 |  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|        1 |     john |  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you meant *"today"* was a variable or the system date, so the following code may need to be modified, but I think it might work:

```
SELECT
    EMP_NAME
FROM
    EMPLOYEE
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM VACATIONS WHERE EMP_NAME = EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME AND
                VACATIONS.VACATION_START_DATE >= Today AND
                VACATIONS.VACATION_END_DATE <= Today)
```